# VB DataView.RowFilter and Cast Before Compare

Tags: vb.net, dataview

In the following DataView.Rowfilter filter, Request_Date is a smalldatetime:

```
dv.RowFilter = "Request_Date >= '01/01/2012' and Request_Date <= '12/31/2012'"
```

The problem with this is that smalldatetime is `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`, but it is compared to a string with the format `'MM/dd/yyyy'`. This means that the filter will automatically convert the strings to smalldatetime, so the comparison only shows date/times between 1/1/2012 at 12AM and 12/31/2012 at 12AM. Any rows with dates later in the day on 12/31/2012 will not get picked up by this filter. I know that I can add a day to the end date or concatenate, say, 12:59:59 to the end of the date to pick up the other times in the day, but I was hoping for somthing more elegant, along the lines of the sql equivalent ...`CONVERT(smalldatetime, Request_Date, 101) <= '12/31/2012'`. Is there any way that I can get a different date format for a DataView field or am I stuck massaging the end date prior to comparison?

FYI, current best option is this:

```
dv.RowFilter = "Request_Date >= #" & dtpStartDate.DateText & "# and Request_Date <= #" & DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, dtpEndDate.DateValue) & "#"
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using at least .NET 3.5, you can use `Linq-To-DataSet` which is more readable:

```
DataTable filtered = dv.Table
          .AsEnumerable()
          .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Request_Date") >= dtpStartDate.Value
                   && r.Field<DateTime>("Request_Date") < dtpEndDate.Value.AddDays(1))
          .CopyToDataTable();
```

Add `using.System.Linq;` and a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`.

Edit: I've only just seen that VB.NET is tagged:

```
Dim filtered = From row In dv.Table
           Where row.Field(Of DateTime)("Request_Date") >= dtpStartDate.Value AndAlso _
                 row.Field(Of DateTime)("Request_Date") < dtpEndDate.Value.AddDays(1)
Dim tblFiltered = filtered.CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: I really appreciate that, Tim, and I probably should have specified that we are still on .NET 2.0 (don't ask).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "<= 12/31/2012", just use "< 1/1/2013" - that is the most elegant and gets exactly what you want.